# Is there any way to connect to a SQL Server that only uses AD auth with Python from Linux?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I've tried several different ways to connect. It works with username and passwords, but trusted connections don't. I used kinit **username** after configuring the /etc/krb5.conf. I can bind my user, but I get the error:

> SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database (851968)

My connection string is:

```
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=servername.fqdn.com;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your connection string to include the spn.
You can the spn by running:

```
setspn -l servername\database
```

or

```
test-DbaSpn -ComputerName servername/database |Out-GridView -PassThru | Set-DbaSpn
```

Once you find the right instance, add it to your connection string.

```
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=servername.fqdn.com;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;ServerSPN=MSSQLSvc/server.fqdn.com:instance;
```

If you get the wrong SPN you will probably receive an error like:

```
sspi provider: message stream modified
```

In my case it was servername:instance that threw me off. I was trying to connect to the instance and got the instance spn instead of the server spn for the instance.

For example, when connecting to the db, I used `instance.domain.com,port` which worked on windows. So, I got the SPN for that instance and received

```
sspi provider: message stream modified
```

I asked a DBA for the SPN and he got the correct SPN of server.domain.com:instance